# how to display months in descending order starting with current month in php

Tags: php

i want to display months in descending order starting from the current month.
Example:

```
The current month is October.
So .. i want to display all 12 months like this..
october
september
august
july
june
may
april
march
february
january
december
november
```

please note ...it should be dynamic..  in the month of november, it should start with november month

This might be helpful... the below code can print days in ascending order??

```
        for ($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++)
{
    $timestamp = time();
    $tm = 86400 * $i; // 60 * 60 * 24 = 86400 = 1 day in seconds
    $tm = $timestamp - $tm;

   echo  $the_date = date("Y-m-d", $tm);
   echo "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Ok. Have you tried anything?

Comment: i just listed the months in sql ... and i tried to pull the records from sql .. with a key in descending order.. Then again .. its not dynamic..